# How can I set the default option in Visual Studio Code's Quick Open View?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Up until now I've been using `Ctrl+Q` to trigger `View: Quick Open View`. The first option was Explorer, so if I `Ctrl+Shift+F` to search something I return the Explorer back to the sidebar by `Ctrl+Q` only.

Today, the first option changed and I have no idea why. It's set to an extension's sidebar view. 
[image]

If I disable it the first option becomes Bookmarks. How can I tell VS Code I want Explorer to be the first option, like it's always been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90232

It was a regression in v1.42 that is due to be fixed in the v1.42.1 recovery update.